# Message Polling in Amazon Standard SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda, which polls messages from a SQS Standard queue from a third party, with the maximum number of messages per polling (10). But, the polling extracts only 2-6 messages most of the time. This leads to the message backlogging in the queue. The queue have a default visibility of 30 sec. Right now, the lambda works on a Cloud Watch trigger. Can, we implement a auto-scaling here, to handle the large volume of data-inflow. And, why the polling picks only less number of messages.

Comment: What are you using for `WaitTimeSeconds` when polling?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of triggering with CloudWatch, you should use [Lambda with SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) which will handle auto scaling for you.

> Lambda uses long polling to poll a queue until it becomes active. When messages are available, Lambda increases the rate at which it reads batches, and invokes your function until it reaches a concurrency limit.

See also [Understanding Scaling Behavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/scaling.html).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But one problem is the SQS is from a third party, so, i am sure whether this works. I have updated the question as well.

Comment: By third party you mean another AWS account? Can you clarify which resources are located where?